# Tkinter - "pack_propagate=0" doesn't work. why?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

To force the width and height of frame widget, with children inside of it (Tkinter Frames always fit theirs children), I used in my code the method "pack_propagate(0)" on the parent frame, but it didn't work.

below an example code. what did I wrong? why the instruction self.f1.pack_propagate=0 doesn't work? Even if I use it, self.f1 frame always fits self.label, why?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):

        self.parent=tk.Tk()
        self.parent.geometry("830x590+370+100")
        self.parent.title("TEST")
        self.parent.minsize(830, 590)

        self.pw=ttk.PanedWindow(self.parent, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.f1=tk.Frame(self.pw, background="white", width=200) # I want width=200!!
        self.f1.pack_propagate=0 # why doesn't work?
        self.f2=tk.Frame(self.pw, background="white")
        self.pw.add(self.f1, weight=0)
        self.pw.add(self.f2, weight=1)
        self.pw.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.label=tk.Label(self.f1, borderwidth=0, background="red", text="HELLO")
        self.label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)   

        self.parent.mainloop()
    
app=MainWindow()
```

Comment: `.pack_propagate()` is a method.  You have to actually call it, rather than destroy it by overwriting it with an integer.

Comment: @jasonharper you are right! thanks Jason, sorry for the simple question, I coded too much, ..